# how to use class in ruby

Tags: ruby

One syntax I am not able to understand is like this:

```
test = heavy::Test.new_test()

test.setq(name)
```

Here `test` is an object and in some other file there is module `heavy` and inside `heavy` there is another module `Test` but after that what is this `new_test()`?

Comment: The subject and the content of the question do not ask the same thing. Is your question, what is `new_test()`? (looks like a method to me.)

Comment: Can you please not say "Hiii frnd" and "plzz help me", or at least say "Hi friend" and "please help me" instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Heavy

end

class Test < Heavy

  def self.new_test  #This is class method (Written as self.method_name or model_name.method_name)
    puts "Hello World"
  end

  def setq(name)    #this is instance method (Call on object of a class not as class method)
   puts "Hello "+name
  end
end
test = Heavy::Test.new_test() # print 'Hello World'
test.setq('Salil')  #print 'Hello Salil'
```

class/module name must be CONSTANT (1st letter should be capital) (i.e.heavy should be Heavy)

Comment: No, there is no method named new_test in my code .thats is my problem.there is no such thing and heavy and Test are module is it create any prob

Comment: but gishu this new_test is nowhere used as a method

Comment: Then it is the method of a super class of test module which is directly accessible to the test. please paste the code of heavy as well as Test

Comment: what do u mean by method of a super class of test module which directy accessible to the test